# Use HibernateCursorItemReader with Entitymanagerfactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, sessionfactory

I'm trying to use **HibernateCursorItemReader** in my Spring batch (for an architectural reason, and I can't use `JpaPagingItemReader` because I don't need pagination). But, the problem is that I have to set the session factory and in my case I have only the `entityManagerFactory`. Unfortunetly, I have to use only an XML configuration for that purpose. I know that in Java code we can make conversion like that:

```
Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory();
```

How can I set my `sessionFactory` property in my `HibernateCursorItemReader`? If I have to make conversion from `entityManagerFactory` to `SessionFactory`? how can I make it directly in an XML config?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the method: getSessionFactory of entityManagerFactory

```
    <bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" factory-bean="entityManagerFactory"
    factory-method="getSessionFactory" />
```